# QGraphicsView artefacts

Tags: c++, qt, qgraphicsview

I'm having some trouble with my QGraphicsView. I've subclass the QGraphicsView to redefine paintEvent. I want to draw some kind a tree using QGraphicsItem for the nodes and QGraphicsLineItem for the edges.

```
void GraphicsView::paintEvent ( QPaintEvent * event ) {
if(arbre!=NULL) {
    arbre->line1->setLine(arbre->text->x(),arbre->text->y(),
                          arbre->text1->x(),arbre->text1->y());

    QGraphicsView::paintEvent(event);
    cout << "redessine" << endl;
}
```

}

But when a I move the nodes to fast, some artefacts (black lines) appear on the view. Any suggestion to get rid of those ?

Comment: Your approach to the problem seems flawed. Normally you add this line to the scene and set the scene to the view. Have you read [this](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/graphicsview.html)?

Comment: Do you have a background set?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Be sure to  include a margin in the `boundingRect()` method of your `QGraphics*Item` subclasses.

http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qgraphicsitem.html#boundingRect

PS: Don't put logic in `paintEvent` method. This method is used to render stuff, not to gather UI field contents or whatever (`arbre->line1->setLine`)

Comment: I think it may be it. I've once badly defined boundingRect() and the problem occured at the slow changing position of view - the items were not drawn corectly (they were not redrawn after they came into visible area of scene. It happens because of viewportUpdateMode and the default value MinimalViewportUpdate - the viewport is beeing redrawn only on places where something changed.

Answer (score 1):

Besides the misplaced logic, call QGraphicsItem::​prepareGeometryChange() before altering an objects geometry. That helped me with a similar problem.